# Select statement for duplicate record search using 2 different codes

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a select statement in SQL that will search the database for duplicate records that have 2 separate codes on it.  In other words it pseudo code would be

Select invoice numbers where the m_code = J or T.  This would give me invoice number 2345 twice, once with code J and once with code T.

Comment: Have you tried `HAVING`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were looking for specific code, then you could use a WHERE clause filter with a HAVING and GROUP BY:

```
select invoice
from yourtable
where m_code in ('J', 'T')
group by invoice
having count(distinct m_code) > 1;
```

But if you want to return and invoices with any two duplicated `m_codes` then you could use:

```
select invoice
from yourtable
group by invoice
having count(distinct m_code) > 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6eb4e/1) of both queries

Comment: The duplication should be on the Invoice number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select invoice_numbers,COUNT(DISTINCT m_code) as CNT
FROM TABLE where m_code in('J','T')
GROUP BY invoice_numbers
HAVING CNT >1;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6eb4e/4)**

Comment: Thank you for input(both of you)  I used the script below and returned 2 columns, which is expected but there, no data in columns:  Select frgt_inv_nbr_s, accessorial_cd
from lu_frgt_inv_accessorial
where accessorial_cd in ('FR','CN')
group by lu_frgt_inv_accessorial.frgt_inv_nbr_s
        ,lu_frgt_inv_accessorial.accessorial_cd
having count(distinct frgt_inv_nbr_s) >= 1;   From this code I get the 2 blank columns FRGT_INV_NBR_S and ACCESSORIAL_CODE. The data I am looking to appear should be invoice nber 2125, accessorial _CD = CN invoice nber 2125, accessorial_CD = FR. What am I missing?