# Sql statement needed to display duplicates to 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I recieved some help but it did not resolve my issue.  I am trying to create the below table from a table that contains multiple invoices numbers and invoice codes.  I want to see the invoices numbers(2 or more of the same number) for any code(multiple codes for the same invoice number is expected)  I am not totally new to SQL but I am by far no expert and look for guidance.  Please see below table

```
 Invoice#      Inv Code 
 22567          CN
 22567          FR
 25855          CN
 25855          FR
```

There are other invoices and other codes in the table, but I only want those codes that have 2 or more of the same invoice number attached to them. Thnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select statement for duplicate record search using 2 different codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494766/select-statement-for-duplicate-record-search-using-2-different-codes)

Comment: Instead of posting a new question on the same subject, update your existing question (and add some more detail, including what you tried and what you expect).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get only records which have two or more invoices of same number. You should try this

```
select *
from tab_name tn
where (select count(*) From tab_name where invoice = tn.invoice) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`Inv Code` FROM table t1
join table t2 ON t1.`Inv Code`=t2.`Inv Code` 
AND t1.`Invoice#`=(SELECT `Invoice#` from table group by `Invoice#`having count(*) >1)
```

OK,try it now.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/922f7/3

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking you can self join on Invoice and get rows where invoice matches and code doesn't.

Hope this sql meets your need:

```
select A.invoice
FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table1 B
ON A.INVOICE=B.invoice
AND A.code<>b.CODE
GROUP BY 1
```